# How to set authorization header in apache camel:ahc

Tags: spring, apache-camel

How do i set the authorization header for ahc component in apache camel? i always hit with org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Authorization Required error. Below is my sample code:

```
<route id="someRouteId">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?period=5s&amp;repeatCount=1"></from>
    <setHeader headerName="Authorization">
        <constant>Basic eWFtYW4pLm5haXJAbWF5bGFiLm19OnlhbWvbgFGH=</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="ahc:https://<someurl>"></to>
    <process ref="processX"></process>
    <to uri="bean:beanX?method=methodX"></to>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `simple` for header

```
<setHeader headerName="Authorization">
    <simple>Basic eWFtYW4pLm5haXJAbWF5bGFiLm19OnlhbWvbgFGH=</simple>
</setHeader>
```